# Counting occurances outside the range of my report

Tags: count

In Crystal Reports XI I am writing a report that displays all companies that have been sent legal referals in the past week.  I want to add a fiel to the report that can count how many times (if any) each company that has been refered this week has been refered in the past.  I am not sure how to execute this since I need to use two different date parameters.  One for the main report (1 week) and one for the past count (3 years).